# Fragment State Pager Adapter Showing Wrong Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a FragmentStatePagerAdapter which shows the details of current Fragment in the next Fragment. Here is the Page Adapter

```
    public class CustomerPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
        {
            public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
            {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {

                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Customer selectedCustomer = mCustomers.get(position);
                String serializedCustomer = gson.toJson(selectedCustomer);
                return CustomerDetailsFragment.newInstance(serializedCustomer);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount()
            {
                return mCustomers.size();
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
            {

                Customer selectedCustomer = mCustomers.get(position);
                String CustomerTitle = selectedCustomer.getFirstName() + " " + selectedCustomer.getLastName();
                return CustomerTitle;
            }   

        }
```

And here is the Fragment where the detail are displayed

```
public static class CustomerDetailsFragment extends Fragment {

    private Customer passedInCustomer;


        public CustomerDetailsFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        public static CustomerDetailsFragment newInstance(String serializedCustomer){

            CustomerDetailsFragment fragment = new CustomerDetailsFragment();

            if (serializedCustomer != null && !serializedCustomer.isEmpty()){
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("customerInfo", serializedCustomer);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
            }


            return fragment;
        }

        private void getPosition(){
            Bundle args = getArguments();
            if (args != null && args.containsKey("customerInfo")){
                String serializedCustomer = (getArguments().getString("customerInfo"));
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                passedInCustomer = gson.fromJson(serializedCustomer, Customer.class);
                }
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_Customer_details, container, false);           


            if (passedInCustomer != null) {
                showCustomerInfo();
            }

            return mRootView;
        }

    }
```

The problem stems from the fact that getItem is called twice for each swipe and the information that need to be displayed are contained in an List so when getItem is called twice the second object in the list is fetched and displayed in the screen where the first object was supposed to be displayed.

Has anyone dealt with displaying an nth number of items in a scrollable ViewPager where you have to create the Fragments on demand. If yes, can you give me suggestions how to deal with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by calling on pager.getCurrentItem() to get the position of the currently displayed item.

Answer (score 2):

I notice that this problem is showing only when I have same fragments with diferent values ( what is probably in the most case ). So after long searching for right answer, i decided to in **getItem()** method every odd time return one fragment and every even time return another fragment ( These fragment are completely same, except their names:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position % 2 == 0){
            return FragmentGalleryImage.newInstance(images.get(position), activity);
        }else{
            return FragmentGalleryImage2.newInstance(images.get(position), activity);
        }

    }
```

And i solved problem nice and smooth.